# I do not know how to indetify these filters

Tags: python, materials, shader-nodes, normal-map, depth-map

I was asked to implement these requirements:

The overall feature is to include the following changes to the process:

If the asset doesn't have a Base Color in the material, you should validate if it has a Normal Map and use it.
If the asset doesn't have a Base Color and Normal Map, just use the Depth Map.

I do understand (kind of) what I have to do, I just do not know how.

For example I saw that by running bpy.data.imagesit gave all the images where it possibly could contain the base color, the problem is, what if the base color is named in another way. Currently the code looks something like this:

```
def load_default_base_color():
    """
    Loads the default base color image if it doesn't exist in Blender data images.
    """
    blend_file_path = bpy.data.filepath
    folder_path = os.path.dirname(blend_file_path)
    image_path = os.path.join(folder_path, "default_textures/base_color_default.png")

    try:
        if "base_color_default" not in bpy.data.images:
            bpy.data.images.load(image_path)    
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error("An error occurred while loading the default base color image: %s", str(e))
```

As you can see, the way the code is structured currently is to validate for "base_color_default" in bpy.data.images, if it's not then I'll go ahead and do something, else, I'll check if there's a normal map. The question is: ¿How do I check if the asset has normal map?, ¿is it through the nodes may be?, ¿is through the images and in such case how (is there a name convention for normal maps or maybe a method to identify its type)?

I would highly appreciate any thoughts or ideas, you can ask me any question if you want and feel that the information provided is not enough.